# How can I add the status of lights "red-yellow" in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I wrote a simple school project traffic light and 
I want to add a new state of "red-yellow" lights

[image]

This picture shows how it should look like

I do not know what the "if-else" statement looks like.

Thank you in advance for your help

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module Traffic
(
  input       reset,
  input       clk,
  input       NS_VEHICLE_DETECT,
  input       EW_VEHICLE_DETECT,
  output wire NS_RED,
  output wire NS_YELLOW,
  output wire NS_GREEN,
  output wire EW_RED,
  output wire EW_YELLOW,
  output wire EW_GREEN
);

reg [5:0] lights; //  {NS_RED, NS_YELLOW, NS_GREEN, EW_RED, EW_YELLOW, EW_GREEN}
reg [4:0] nsCounter;
reg [3:0] ewCounter;
reg [1:0] yellowCounter;


assign {NS_RED, NS_YELLOW, NS_GREEN, EW_RED, EW_YELLOW, EW_GREEN} = lights;


always @(posedge clk)
   if (reset)
      lights <= 6'b001100;
   else
     if (nsCounter == 31 & EW_VEHICLE_DETECT & NS_GREEN)
       lights <= 6'b010100;
     else
       if (ewCounter == 15 & EW_GREEN) 
         lights <= 6'b100010;
       else
         if (yellowCounter == 3 & NS_YELLOW)
           lights <= 6'b100001;
         else
           if (yellowCounter == 3 & EW_YELLOW) 
             lights <= 6'b001100;
//------------------------------------

always @(negedge clk)
  if (reset)
    begin
      nsCounter     <= 5'h0;
      ewCounter     <= 4'h0;
      yellowCounter <= 2'h0;
    end
  else
    begin
      nsCounter     <= nsCounter     + 1'b1;
      ewCounter     <= ewCounter     + 1'b1; 
      yellowCounter <= yellowCounter + 1'b1;
    end
//------------------------------------

endmodule
//====================================
```

Comment: What is your verilog question?

Comment: how to write an instruction if-else to add a red-yellow state

Comment: You need to create a state machine. Start with drawing one. Look around for verilog examples of the FSM implementations. Usually people use the 'case' statement instead of the if-else.

Comment: You would help me to write that I am a beginner and this is a project for school :(

Comment: Sorry, but no one knows your level of knowledge here. So, it is impossible to help you without programming the example from scratch. This is not a task for the forum. Again, i suggest you to start with studying FSM, i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Answer (score 0):

You have written a priority encoder here, where the last condition only applies if none of the others are valid. This is often slower to implement (unless the synthesis tool can optimise away unreachable state), and it is harder to scale (as you have discovered).

It is also harder to analyse in terms of checking that the flow from each state is correct for all possible states.

Even though it may look less optimal, it is more common to write the state machine as a case statement using the state variable. You then unroll the 'for each state, the next state condition is ...' expressions.

Using the encoding implied in the *image*, this would be an obvious case expression

```
2'b01: nextState = (counter == 5'h0f) ? 2'b10 : 2'b01;
```

Based on the state/nextstate, you can also determine what behaviour the counter needs. Bear in mind that if you have more than one counter, you have some implicit assumptions about the correlation between count states and light states.

The non-obvious part of this question is that you may not want a 4 state sequence (as indicated in the diagram, where the axes take 'inverted' states), you have up to 16 potential states because you have two sets of lights. It is up to you to first draw out all the possible paths from one of the 'stable' states, working out which states you need to avoid (e.g. G/G). This is another reason to decouple the state variables from the outputs.